# Copy a single record to a replica table before update using trigger (Oracle 12c)

Tags: oracle, trigger

I want to insert a complete record (before updating original record) to a replica table using trigger. Following are the sample tables:

```
create table customer
(
     cID number,
     cName varchar2(30)
     -- all other attributes will be defined here
);

create table replica
as (select * from customer where 1 = 2);
```

and trigger:

```
create or replace trigger update_Trigger
before update on customer
for each row
begin
    if updating then
        insert into replica
            select * from customer where cID = :old.cID;
          -- also done with :new.cID; but not effect...
    end if;
end;
```

Table is not empty, I have some records in it. But when I run update statement on **customer** table, I get error:

```
SQL> UPDATE CUSTOMER
  2  SET CNAME = 'C' WHERE CID = 102;


UPDATE CUSTOMER
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04091: table DBADMIN.CUSTOMER is mutating, trigger/function may no
ORA-06512: at "DBADMIN.UPDATE_TRIGGER", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'DBADMIN.UPDATE_TRIGGER'
```

What is wrong with this? What am I missing? I know this can be done by using **:new.attribute** and **:old.attribute** but there many attributes in the original table, I am working on. Is there any short method for getting and inserting the whole row?

Comment: You have to use :new. It's mutating for a reason. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5432/what-are-the-causes-and-solutions-for-mutating-table-errors

Comment: @Phil: I have already mentioned that I have used **:new.cID**  but nothing for good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this format for copying your original values over:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_Trigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON customer
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF UPDATING THEN
        INSERT INTO  replica VALUES(:OLD.cID, :OLD.cName, ... );
    END IF;
END;
/
```

You will need to specify each field you want inserted into `replica`

This will be slow and cause a lot of network/database traffic if you are updating 1,000s of rows at a time.